# Previewing camera through java using Direct Show and Java ( JNA/JNI )

Tags: java, c++, camera, java-native-interface, directshow

I need to show a camera preview in a java application.
I am using DirectShow natively and using JNA as a bridge between Java and C++. I have  a  few questions regarding this :-

1) In DirectShow I can either use Sample Grabber to take the raw bytes or use capture graph in window or windowless mode . Which approach should be better provided that I want to show the preview in a Java applet.

2) How this rendering information be sent to the java side ? 
   -- Do i need to run a timer on the java side and consistently ask for frame from native code ?
  or
   -- Should I get the native window handle of the java window and pass it to the directShow to paint on it directly ?

I am pretty new to Java,JNA/JNI and direct show. Please let me know what would be the right approach and how to go about it ?

Comment: It'll likely be more efficient to pass the window handle to the native code (JNA provides a `Native.getWindowHandle()` function).  If you use a buffer, you'll need to translate that buffer into a format usable by  Java2d, which will probably be a non-trivial operation.

Comment: Is you source open?  I'd like to see it since I need to do the same.  I'm using JNI and use videoInput but I want to port to JNA and avoid c++.